# cordova frame work 7 youtube iframe not loading in ios after phonegap build

Tags: cordova, iframe, youtube-api, cordova-plugins, html-framework-7

i have been struggling to show iframe in ios . its almost now 7 days i have been trying to load youtube iframe in ios . i have installed cordova whitelist plugin and assign * to access , allow-intent , allow-navigation  . i have set the meta content policy to

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src * 'unsafe-eval'; child-src *; connect-src * 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'; style-src * 'unsafe-inline';">
```

my iframe code is

```
 <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_upOB_WF2y8?rel=0" style="width: 100%; " allowfullscreen ></iframe>
```

and my config.xml after xdk build package

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android-versionCode="1" ios-CFBundleVersion="undefined" version="0.0.1" id="not.yet.specified"  >
<!-- This file was generated by the Intel XDK Cordova Package Build tool. -->
<name>Trinfinity Academy</name>
<description>Trinfinity Academy</description>
<author>trinfinityacademy.com</author>
<content src="index.html"/>
<preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />
<platform name="android" >
    <allow-intent href="*"/>
    <allow-navigation href="*"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
</platform>
<platform name="ios" >
    <allow-intent href="*"/>
    <allow-navigation href="*"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
</platform>
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.2.0" />
<preference name="xwalkMultipleApk" value="false" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview" spec="1.8.0"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-background-app" spec="https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-background-app"/> <!-- If available via Cordova registry; consider changing to an NPM reference. -->
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="3.2.2"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.2.2"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-in-app-youtube" spec="https://github.com/davidefavia/cordova-plugin-in-app-youtube"/> <!-- If available via Cordova registry; consider changing to an NPM reference. -->
<platform name="android" >
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23"/>
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
    <preference name="android-signed" value="true"/>
    <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTop"/>
</platform>
<platform name="ios" >
    <preference name="deployment-target" value="8.0"/>
    <preference name="ios-configuration" value="adhoc"/>
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
</platform>
<config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest/application" mode="merge"> 
    <activity android:launchMode="singleTop" />
</config-file>
</widget>
```

but still the iframe is not loading in ios 11 on iphone 8 plus

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: i already added the code . full snippet can not be uploaded here

Comment: plus all relevent  information is provided here

Comment: can you share the logs if there are issues/error encountered?

Comment: hi thanks for standing by my problem . i am not a nerd of cordova . but did you ask for log that is generated while phonegap compile's code ?

Comment: I think so, here is the guide for debugging in [phonegap](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/Debugging-in-PhoneGap)

Comment: thanks i am digging into it